# How to set up codecept.conf.js for both android native and ios native in the same project

Tags: android, ios, codeceptjs

I've worked through the docs and am not finding a solution to this problem.  What I'm trying to do is configure codeceptJS properly so as to be able to execute tests against both native iOS and native Android within the same project.  The docs seem to suggest that one can craft test cases which can target both android and iOS at the same time, e.g.

```
I.click({android: '//android.widget.Button', ios: '//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[1]'});
```

However, it's not clear how one would configure the appium helper in codecept.conf.js in order to accomplish this, and I have not been able to uncover any documentation that explains it.  In particular, it seems like the Appium helper can accept *either* an android .apk or an iOS .app / .ipa for app, but not both.

Would appreciate any insight the community might have on how to achiever this.  I can run against with android or iOS via different projects... but I would much rather do both via the same project, and if possible from the same test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need to configure a script for both android and ios in your package.json, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "ios": "PLATFORM=iOS APP='/path/to/example.app' DEVICE='iPhone 12 Pro Max' VERSION=14.4 npx codeceptjs run --steps",
  "android": "PLATFORM=Android APP='/path/to/example.apk' DEVICE='Pixel 2' VERSION=9 PACKAGE=com.exampleapp ACTIVITY=MainActivity npx codeceptjs run --steps"},
```

Then you can use each of the following commands in terminal:

```
npm run ios

npm run android
```

If you are using Appium, so you need to configure your codecept.conf.js file this way:

```
  helpers: {
   Appium: {
   //platform: 'Android',
   platform: 'iOS',
   //app: '/path/to/example.apk',
   app: '/path/to/example.app',
   desiredCapabilities: {
    deviceName: 'iPhone 12 Pro Max',
    platformVersion: undefined,
    appPackage: '',
    appActivity: '',
    automationName: 'XCUITest' //in case your xcode version is not updated
  }
 }
```